# Invalid contents in structure.sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rails-migrations

My application is on Heroku platform. I also use Heroku CI to automatically run all tests when deploying.

Recently I saw that my tests don't pass, there is line in error: 
`relation "relation_name" does not exist`.

Although this table is available on production.

Since Heroku CI uses `structure.sql` to run tests, I looked at this file and noticed that when creating new tables using migrations, something like this is not written to this file:

```
CREATE TABLE public.currencies (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying,
    rate_to_eur numeric(6,3),
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Now only thing that is written to structure.sql is migration numbers:

```
INSERT INTO "schema_migrations" (version) VALUES
('20161231110102'),
('20161231133210'),
('20161231134345'),
```

I tried doing `rake db:structure:dump`, but nothing changed in structure.

At the same time, tests run without problems on local machine.

How do I fix bug in tests on heroku?

Comment: Heroku doesn't run migrations by default did you configured procfile for it?